# jquery autocomplete with different sources

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I hope you can help me. I'm looking for a possibility to make my jquery autocompleter use a different source whether the first input is a digit or a letter (on the fly). I tried days and could not make it working.

Thats the autocomplete code:

```
$(function() {

$("#ac1").autocomplete(
'search.php', //or blub.php
{onItemSelect: function(item) {

var text = 'test';
$("#num1").val(item.data);

var selector = $("#num1").val();
var additionalradius = selector.substring(0,3);
var zip = selector.substring(6);
$("#num1").val(additionalradius);
$("#3rd").val(zip);
alert (additionalradius);
}},

{selectFirst: true}
);

});
```

So I need something like "if first key in field #ac1 is a number, then use search.php. Else use blub.php" in that code shown. Any idea? Thank you for you help.

Comment: I would suggest you trying this: parseInt(yourInputString.charAt(0)) > 0

Comment: Check out some  of them here http://jqueryplugin.net/category/autocomplete/

Comment: I checked that website with all these autocompleters already but none of these offers the funktionality I need :(
The parseInt idea is quite nice, but I cannot make it work with my autocompleter code I showed. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

To set the `source` option in search event ( that is triggered before a search is performed ) is one way to do it.

```
$("#ac1").autocomplete({
    source: 'search.php',
    search: function( event, ui ) {
        if ( isNaN( parseInt( $(this).val().charAt(0) ) ) )
            $(this).autocomplete( 'option', 'source', 'blub.php' );
        else
            $(this).autocomplete( 'option', 'source', 'search.php' );
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**

```
$("#ac1").autocomplete({
    source: 'search.php',
    search: function( event, ui ) { /* code from search function here */ },
    select: function( event, ui ) { /* code for item select here */ }
    /* additional options */
});
```

Comment: thank you. I added your suggestion to my code (you can see I updated it here also) and get an error in the line {onItemSelect: function(item) {

Comment: @thevibe, what's with all that syntax errors, check the answer update.